# copy pandas Excel Dataframe to clipboard without index header

Tags: python, excel, pandas, clipboard

I have an Excel file from Where I have to copy some subset of data to the clipboard so that I can paste it to any place. I am using pandas `DataFrame.to_clipboard(excel=True, sep=None, **kwargs)` function but I don't want index headers to be copied.

**What it is copying is this:**

[image: Excel Copied]

**What I want to copy is this only:**

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you have to pass two parameters for that : index and header.

```
DataFrame.to_clipboard(excel=True, sep=None, index=False, header=None)
```